# how ES6 imports and exports works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am writing react application and i has dir with actions files my example action file looks like

```
export const USER_LOADING_START = 'USER_LOADING_START';
export const USER_LOADED = 'USER_LOADED';

export function userLoadingStart() {
    return {
        type: USER_LOADING_START
    };
}

export function userDataLoaded(value) {
    return {
        type: USER_LOADED,
        payload: {
            value: value
        }
    };
}
```

and in actions dir i have a file named index.js which content is

```
import * as userActions from './userActions';

let exp = {
    ...userActions,
};

export default exp;
```

So in other files i want to import my action creators so i use:

```
import {userLoadingStart} from './actions';
```

and it doesn't work but if i write:

```
import actions from '../actions';

const { userLoadingStart } = actions;
```

then it is working correctly, so what am i doing wrong ?

i tried

```
export {
    ...userActions,
    ...spinnerActions,
    ...errorActions
}
```

and

```
export exp
```

but it doesn't compile by webpack

Comment: "*but it doesn't compile by webpack*"... please include the compiler error message in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So in other files i want to import my action creators so i use:
>
> ```
> import {userLoadingStart} from './actions';
> ```

For that to work, it means `./actions` must export named values. The issue is that your logic currently bundles everything up and exports it as single named export named `default`. The easiest way to do that would be for your index to do

```
export * from './userActions';
```

to essentially pass everything from `./userActions` through as exports of `./actions`.